# Formating output text in awk and open in document

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, formatting

I have a data set like this:

```
BRCC    hete    1   15869   105A
BRAC    he  1   1799967 956G
BCAS    he  2   7334543 369AFVC
RCA he  4   9534262 7806-14
RCA he  5   144848  1114A
RA  he  5   206118  52A
BCAVV   he  5   543304  3807TCD
BCA hoo 1   106091515   4308TDDSC
BCA hoo 1   206075  4563A
BCA hoo 1   799917  2612CDSA
BCA hoo 2   206076  513G
BCA hoom    3   16941   3113A
```

Dataset have 6 column and is tab separate. I would like to format text and add header. My solution is:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{printf "%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t \n" ,"TEST","HEADER","CLASS","CLASS2","SVGH" pritnf "\n" "__________________________________________________"} {printf "%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t \n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' in.txt > out.doc
```

But I need to save output to document and open in LibreOffice. But output looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to formating text to keep columns under header - to be better readable? Like this:

[image]

**NOTE: I will apperciate any help not only awk solution.**

Comment: First determine the space needed by each column, then in Perl you can add spaces like this `perl -E 'printf "%-10s%-10s\n", "BRCC", "hoom"'`

Comment: First document is output from my awk script. Second Image is only edited by myself in LibreOffice

Comment: @HåkonHægland, Thank you for reply. It is possible to write whole syntax? Perl I really do not know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like this is all you need:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "TEST","HEADER","CLASS","CLASS2","SVGH"} 1' file | column -t
TEST   HEADER  CLASS  CLASS2     SVGH
BRCC   hete    1      15869      105A
BRAC   he      1      1799967    956G
BCAS   he      2      7334543    369AFVC
RCA    he      4      9534262    7806-14
RCA    he      5      144848     1114A
RA     he      5      206118     52A
BCAVV  he      5      543304     3807TCD
BCA    hoo     1      106091515  4308TDDSC
BCA    hoo     1      206075     4563A
BCA    hoo     1      799917     2612CDSA
BCA    hoo     2      206076     513G
BCA    hoom    3      16941      3113A
```

and then use a constant-width font in LibreOffice to display it. To underscore the header line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "TEST","HEADER","CLASS","CLASS2","SVGH"} 1' file | column -t |
    awk '{print} NR==1{gsub(/./,"_"); print}'
TEST   HEADER  CLASS  CLASS2     SVGH
_____________________________________
BRCC   hete    1      15869      105A
BRAC   he      1      1799967    956G
BCAS   he      2      7334543    369AFVC
RCA    he      4      9534262    7806-14
RCA    he      5      144848     1114A
RA     he      5      206118     52A
BCAVV  he      5      543304     3807TCD
BCA    hoo     1      106091515  4308TDDSC
BCA    hoo     1      206075     4563A
BCA    hoo     1      799917     2612CDSA
BCA    hoo     2      206076     513G
BCA    hoom    3      16941      3113A
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ed, this look much more easy than I thought. Is there any way to keep "_____" this line under the header?

Comment: `... column -t |  sed 2i$(printf "_%.0s" {1..42})`

Comment: I added a subsequent awk command that'd underscore the header line.

Comment: @karakfa nice solution thank you so much! Is there any way to print the same lane on the end of table? So create "borders"?

Comment: @Paul change 2 to $, but you may need to put all in single quotes.  However, if you're using awk already, it would be easier to add an END block there to do the same.